# Unable to see Xamarin insight events

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.insights

I've setup Xamarin Insights, and was able t catch 2 exceptions. I added some Xamarin.Insights.Track(...... statements to track some functionality.
However I can not see this on the web portal. The overview displays 5 users 80+ sessions and 2 open issues (the exceptions). Is the Tracking/event feature a special paid feature or?

Comment: Could you show us how you implemented the functionality? Right now, it is difficult to tell if there issue lies herein

Comment: Current issue is to get the package HockeySDK.Xamarin 4.1.0-beta1
The project (Xamarin Forms) targets portable-net45+win+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10 and the nuget package can not be installed

Comment: I Tested it in a plain Xamarin.iOS and it worked as expected, but current project is Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(While this response is bit late, maybe it's still useful?)*

**Short version:** Insights `Event tracking` is a paid feature.

**Longer version:** In order to gain access to Insights `Event tracking` you would need to upgrade your Insights subscription tier to an Enterprise level *(which I'm not sure is possible post-merge)*.  At this point you would benefit more by migrating your app to utilize HockeyApp (if you haven't already).  I suppose if you absolutely need this functionality, perhaps you could write into Xamarin support or sales.

*Old Xamarin Insights tier page via web.archive.org (https://web.archive.org/web/20160304014709/http://xamarin.com/insights#pricing)* [image: old insights pricing]

Comment: Thanks, I think I was in the middle of the transition of hockey app/insights.